# Monitor and injection support broadcom 4313

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, broadcom

I have a laptop with the broadcom 4313 wifi card. So far I've tried 2 drivers - `brcmsmac` and `wl`. The first is an opensource one and the second is a closed source vendor one.

With the `brcmsmac` I'm experiencing bad signals, so it's unusable. With the closed source driver I read that I had to do `echo 1 > /proc/brcm_monitor0` and it should create `prism0`, but didn't work as well.

So is there anyway I can use my wlan card to monitor and inject? The `brcmsmac` is not an option since the signal is close to non-existing. I know there are a lot of threads about this, but I don't see any concrete answer or solution.